# password_hash/password_salt vs password_digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, salt, digest

I'm currently going through Michael Hartl's book (Ruby on Rails tutorial 3rd edition) and he uses `password_digest` with his authentication model, I checked out Pragmatic Studio's Rails course and in their sample video, they use `passowrd_hash/password_salt` in their authentication model. From wikipediaing, it seems that salt is a standard use in cryptography and has a variety of uses for security. All I could really find on password_digest is it works with a rails method `has_secure_password`.

Is one preferred over the other or do they serve different purposes ultimately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually building a salted hash (based on e.g. SHA1) was indeed a long time the default way to store passwords. However, since a couple of years, it became clear that there need to be better (i.e. more secure) ways to store a password which ensure that even if an attacker could gain access to the raw hashes, they could not easily brute-force them.

As such, in newer Rails versions, passwords are by default saved with `has_secure_password` using the [Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) algorithm which is much more suitable for password storage than a simple salted hash. Note that Bcrypt also uses a salt internally. You just don't have to deal with it yourself.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Question, I'm currently messing around with [this example](http://nycda.com/blog/basic-user-authentication-model-in-rails-4/) this would be an example of the older way correct?

Comment: The tutorial uses the same hashing algorithm. It just builds everything from hand which might not be necessary if you use `has_secure_password`. However, in any case you should try to get a good understanding about how all these solutions work. A significant part of the security of your app will depend on this.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've been following this and Hartl's guide on rolling my own authentication model for that exact reason you stated. In many other screencasts they just tell you to use Devise, and let the "magic" take care of the heavy lifting, but I like to know the details. I'm not looking to merely patch a bunch of gems together, I want to learn how RoR works from a low level standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

when using the `has_secure_password` a lot of the encryption magic is done automatically for you, and a few functions are exposed that make it easier for you to verify the password of a User.

As taken from the has_secure_password documentation:

```
# Schema: User(name:string, password_digest:string)
class User < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_secure_password 
end

user = User.new(name: 'david', password: '', password_confirmation: 'nomatch') 
user.save
# => false, password required

user.password = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe'
user.save
# => false, confirmation doesn't match

user.password_confirmation = 'mUc3m00RsqyRe'
user.save                                             
# => true 

user.authenticate('notright')                                   
# => false
user.authenticate('mUc3m00RsqyRe')                              
# => user
User.find_by(name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'notright')
# => false 
User.find_by(name: 'david').try(:authenticate, 'mUc3m00RsqyRe')
# => user
```

Both systems you mentioned will work, it just comes down on what you wish to use, what options you  have available etc.

Answer (score 1):

The method Hartl uses, `has_secure_password`, [uses](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) an algorithm called Bcrypt to salt and hash a password, producing a `password_digest` string that has three components:

1. A flag that indicates that the string is a Bcrypt hash
2. The (unhashed) salt
3. The result of hashing password+salt

I'm not familiar with the Pragmatic Studio course, but it sounds like they're storing the salt and hash in different attributes.